# Populate New Column Based on Conditional Match in Another Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

Using either dplyr, apply, and/or an ifelse statement, I would like to determine if each pair of x and y coordinates of df_1 are between one of a series of unique xmin & xmax and ymin & ymax coordinates of df_2. For each successful match, or "hit", I would like to populate a new column, df_1$region, with the corresponding df_2$region label.

For example:

```
set.seed(806)
# df_1
df_1 <- data.frame(
  region= 0, 
  x = sample(seq(-2, 2, .05), 5, replace = TRUE), 
  y = sample(seq(0.5, 4.5, .05), 5, replace = TRUE))

# df_2
df_2 <- data.frame(
region = sample(1:16, 16),
xmin = rep(seq(-2, 1, 1), each = 4),
xmax = rep(seq(-1, 2, 1), each = 4),
ymin = rep(seq(0.5, 3.5, 1), times = 4),
ymax = rep(seq(1.5, 4.5, 1), times = 4))
```

Thus, df_1 should be:

```
region     x    y
    13 -1.00 0.60
    11  0.95 1.55
    13 -1.30 1.00
    5  -1.40 3.05
    4   1.25 4.50
```

The following figure should help visualize the locations of each of the 16 comparison regions in df_2.

[image: SEE COMPARISON REGIONS]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I get an answer with `library(tidyverse); df_1 %>% mutate(region = map2_int(x, y, ~df_2$region[.x > df_2$xmin & .x <= df_2$xmax & .y > df_2$ymin & .y <= df_2$ymax]))`, but the regions are different.

Comment: @alistaire Your code seems to be working as expected. I think the regions are mislabeled in the example dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `purrr::map2` (or `base::mapply`, if you prefer) to iterate over the `x` and `y` values, comparing each set to the minimums and maximums in `df_2` and using the result to subset `df_2$region`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(806)

df_1 <- data_frame(region = 0, 
                   x = sample(seq(-2, 2, .05), 5, replace = TRUE), 
                   y = sample(seq(0.5, 4.5, .05), 5, replace = TRUE))

df_2 <- data_frame(region = sample(1:16, 16),
                   xmin = rep(seq(-2, 1, 1), each = 4),
                   xmax = rep(seq(-1, 2, 1), each = 4),
                   ymin = rep(seq(0.5, 3.5, 1), times = 4),
                   ymax = rep(seq(1.5, 4.5, 1), times = 4))

df_1 %>% 
    mutate(region = map2_int(x, y, 
                             ~df_2$region[.x > df_2$xmin & 
                                          .x <= df_2$xmax & 
                                          .y > df_2$ymin & 
                                          .y <= df_2$ymax]))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   region      x     y
#>    <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     16 -1.00  0.600
#> 2     12  0.950 1.55 
#> 3     16 -1.30  1.00 
#> 4      8 -1.40  3.05 
#> 5      9  1.25  4.50
```